# MySQL select the count of 2 relations

Tags: mysql, sql

I am implementing a voting system with MySQL and Node.js, it's working good for now, but there is 1 question. I have a table *articles* with 2 relations *upvotes* and *downvotes*.

If I fetch all my articles, I'd like to have the count of *upvotes* and *downvotes*. First table is working with

```
SELECT articles.*, count(downvotes.articles_id) 
as downvotes 
from articles 
left join downvotes 
on (articles.id = downvotes.articles_id) 
where articles.communities_id = '52' 
group by articles.id 
ORDER BY created_at 
DESC [![Sequel Pro][1]][1]
```

How can I add the *upvotes* in the query too?

Thanks!

matz

Comment: same way you did the downvotes

Comment: 2 joins is quite easy task for Mysql. Do it.

Answer (score 2):

Same way you added the downvotes. Also, make sure you get into the habit of formatting your SQL, makes it far easier to read and debug.

```
SELECT 
    articles.*,
    COUNT(downvotes.articles_id) AS downvotes,
    COUNT(upvotes.articles_id) AS upvotes
FROM
    articles
        LEFT JOIN
    downvotes ON (articles.id = downvotes.articles_id)
        LEFT JOIN
    upvotes ON (articles.id = upvotes.articles_id)
WHERE
    articles.communities_id = '52'
GROUP BY articles.id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much, well formatted is a good point.

Comment: No there is an error in syntax :/ I got same count for downvotes / upvotes but I've only 1 downvote and 2 upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Add another left join for upvotes

```
SELECT articles.*, count(downvotes.articles_id) as downvotes 
from articles 
left join downvotes on (articles.id = downvotes.articles_id) 
left join upvotes on (articles.id = upvotes.articles_id) 
where articles.communities_id = '52' 
group by articles.id 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a friend posted the correct answer:

`` SELECT a.id,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM downvotes d WHERE a.id=d.articles_id) AS `downs`,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM upvotes u WHERE a.id=u.articles_id) AS `ups`
FROM articles a
ORDER BY a.id ASC ``

He told me the problem is the group at the end. The results from the first left join will be overwritten with the second left join.